# Unusual Source in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

When I'm reviewing the sources of my pages within Analytics, I'm occasionally seeing some values that appear to be incorrect/impossible. I'm not seeing it often, but definitely enough to skew some reports unless I add to my filter.

I'm seeing a couple development sites that I'm working on (which have no relation to the production site that I'm viewing reports for) as sources for traffic to the site. These development sites have 0 links to the production site, so I'm not sure how Analytics is seeing them as sources of traffic in any way. There are times when I have both the production site and these development sites open in separate tabs on the same browser, but that's about the closest they are to connecting in any way.

Any ideas on how this could occur?

Comment: Checked access logs? bots are notorious for browsing websites, and even those with ignore in robots and noindex on pages.

Comment: Did you verify there's no analytics code on the development sites that could be crossing the streams one way or another?

Answer (score 1):

As @joshuahedlund suggested this is probably leakage from your development site, this can be solved in one of two ways:

1. Site specific configuration of GA
2. GA Filters

For the first you ensure that you don't have your public account configured in your development site and vice versa by having one central place, outside of your versioning, in which you configure the GA code.

For the second you explicitly set in GA which domain you want tracked in the profile by going to Admin -> Profiles -> Filters -> New Filter and excluding all except for the subdomain you want the data for, as shown [here](http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/)

Naturally best would be both.